# Can WSO2 ESB play the role of an HTTP(S) proxy for mediating incoming REST API requests?

Tags: api, rest, ssl, http-proxy, wso2-esb

**Background:**

*I'm trying to use WSO2 ESB within a corporate setting to provide authenticated access to underlying REST API backend providers located either within the enterprise, or on the internet.*

My goal is to selectively grant access, e.g. to REST API provider P1 only to REST client C1 and to to REST API provider P2 only to REST client C2.

Using WSO2 ESB with the "<api>" as described into http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/implementing-restful-services-wso2-esb/ seems to impose to redefine every resource, which can be very large and error prone for complex APIs (e.g. vmware vcloud director REST API https://www.vmware.com/support/vcd/doc/rest-api-doc-1.5-html/landing-user_operations.html)

Using the WSO2 ESB "<proxy>", as described into
https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-RESTClientandRESTService ("REST Client and REST Service") imposes that the URIs exposed to HTTP clients will be modified modified w.r.t. to the original backed uri. Typical proxy URIs will be of the following form with the services prefix and a specific port http://<wso2_host>:8280/services/CustomerServiceProxy/customers/123

While having modified exposed URIs is fine when the client can be controlled (typically an in house custom REST API). It is problematic when the REST API is an industry standard and the client is an SDK, or an off-the-shelf application which is outside of the control of WSO2 users (e.g. AWS S3 API, or vmware vcloud director REST API)

In addition, some custom clients/SDKs may verify server-side SSL certificates against a public key embedded into the SDK/client.

The usual solution to preserve the HTTP REST API as-is and add some authentication on top of it is to expose the API through an HTTP proxy (possibly authenticating clients through HTTP proxy authentication), i.e. client send a CONNECT request prior to sending their original request. This preserves the full URIs and also the SSL certificates.

**Question:**

Is there a way to have WSO2 ESB play the role of an HTTP(S) proxy for mediating incoming REST API requests, preserving original URIs and server SSL certificates ?

I'm thinking about a new "<http-proxy>" syntax, I haven't yet spotted. I.e. it would listen to http://<wso2_host>:3128/ and respond to CONNECT requests.  The mediation would then have the ability to accept or not the CONNECT depending on the CONNECT request inputs (proxy authentication, requested host), and other http transport headers). Once the CONNECT request is granted, it might even be possible to act on subsequent individual proxified requests

Best specs describing the CONNECT behavior seem https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01 (1999 draft that seems adopted) and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22#page-29 proposed standard.

For HTTPS URI, there might be limited ability within the WSO2 mediation: the HTTP request is SSL encrypted and only the domain can be known if SNI (Server Name Indication) is specified in the request. At least this would enable to grant/deny some host names to a set of clients depending on proxy authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to try the `<property name="preserveProcessedHeaders" value="true"/>` in your `<inSequence>`.  This property will pass all security headers through the proxy.  I'm not sure about server certificates.

Here is an example of that property in use:
https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Sample+153%3A+Routing+Messages+that+Arrive+to+a+Proxy+Service+without+Processing+Security+Headers

I hope tlevel for API usehat helps.  You may also want to look into the wso2 API manager, which lets you selectively grant access to APIs.